# Upgrading dependencies issue with Cinnamon

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, cinnamon, locale

I'm facing an issue when I'm trying to upgrade my Arch Linux system the new version of the package *cinnamon-translations-3.6.2.1* it gets stuck during an upgrade. When I run `pacman -Syu` I get this message:

```
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/af/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/am/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/as/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ast/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/az/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/be/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/be@latin/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/bg/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/bn/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/bn_IN/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/br/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/bs/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ca/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ca@valencia/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/crh/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/cy/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/dz/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/el/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/en@shaw/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/eo/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/et/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/eu/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/fa/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/fi/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ga/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/gu/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/hi/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/id/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ka/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/km/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/kn/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ku/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/lt/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/lv/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/mai/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/mg/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/mk/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ml/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/mn/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/mr/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ms/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/nb/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/nds/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ne/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/nn/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/nso/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/oc/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/or/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/pa/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ro/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/rw/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/si/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/sk/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/sl/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/sq/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/sr/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/sr@latin/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ta/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/te/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/th/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/ug/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/uk/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/wa/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/xh/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
cinnamon-translations: /usr/share/locale/zu/LC_MESSAGES/cinnamon-settings-daemon.mo exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

I tried to remove it and upgrade it separately but still no success.

What are my options here?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#.22Failed_to_commit_transaction_.28conflicting_files.29.22_error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this issue was related to EOL of 32bit Arch system. I filed a bug report to Arch support following the steps in [this article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#.22Failed_to_commit_transaction_.28conflicting_files.29.22_error) and as I understood the people who answered that the most obvious issue is that i686 is no longer supported and the repository for the required (conflicted) package is down now.

So I switched to this [Archlinux32 repository](https://bbs.archlinux32.org/) suggested by Arch devs.